# How to manage presence in background iOS+Pubnub .?

Tags: ios, chat, pubnub

I have created a chat application using Pubnub Framework. For that i have enable presence for a single channel and all user subscribe that channel. But when i close the app (Background Mode) pubnub gives me Timeout statement for that user.

But i want to show user Online until user terminate the app.

How we will manage this scenario ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 5):

I've never used PubNub but looking at the documentation for it, I see a couple things you possibly need to do:

1) You need to get your PubNub delegate to return "`YES`" for the method [`shouldRunClientInBackground`](https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c#--boolshouldrunclientinbackground).

or

2) You can modify your app's plist file to say it needs to run in the background.  [This Apple Technote for background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) tells you how to do it.

Comment: However, the apps that keep presence alive in background is likely to be rejected by Apple, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I have done the shouldRunClientInBackground= yes but app will be terminated after 30 second in background. This cause the issue to manage the presence (Online/offline). Pubnub disconnect in background after 30 seconds.

Comment: Just a question, how does Whatsapp keep connection/presence alive in the background? But not rejected by Apple?

Comment: @John - Look at point #2 in my answer -- it's a flag (or attribute) set in the app's plist file that tells iOS to keep the app running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Background App Refresh and make a presence heartbeat request.

Here's a simple explanation for [Background App Refresh](http://www.scottyloveless.com/blog/2014/background-app-refresh-explained)

Feel free to google around for more results

You're limited to about 30 seconds to do all your work (should be enough time if you have a valid connection). You can also control the interval of the background fetch. Looks like you'll have to implement some of this yourself, but it should be doable on iOS 7 and iOS 8.